# Gestures are disables in userControl inside another user control

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I have written a user control that triggers an action with a swipe gesture, when I use the control inside another user control, the swipe gesture doesn't work while it works when it is used separately ? It doesn't even work when it is used in ListView either for some reason !

Comment: Can you give the code for "used inside another control" and "used separately"?

Comment: UserControl with gesture be <ctrl:SlidingPanel/> then second user control is <StackPanel> <ctrl:SlidingPanel/> <Grid> <Blah blah blah/> </StackPanel>